# Is it possible to iterate through all of a dictionary's keys except a specific subset?

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary with the keys being all the numbers 1-10. And I want to iterate through that excluding keys 6-8. Is it possible to do something like

```
for key in dictionary.keys().exclude([1,2,3])
```

I've made up `.exclude()` to demonstrate what I want to do.

Comment: Why not create a new dict without those keys?

Comment: You can have an if statement right under for loop with the list to exclude. Alternatively you can also subtract the values to be excluded from dict.keys() since essentially dict.keys() is a set. This would be something like for key in (dict.keys()-set([1,2,3]))

Comment: @anik jha thanks I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the keys of a dictionary are unique, so using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) operations would be suitable (and are very performant):

```
dictionary = {i: i for i in range(1, 11, 1)}

for key in set(dictionary) - set([1, 2, 3]):
    print(key)
```

You can also use a set literal instead of an explicit `set` conversion like this:

```
for key in set(dictionary) - {1, 2, 3}:
    print(key)
```

And, as pointed out in the comments, `dictionary.keys()` as you originally had it would behave in the same way as `set(dictionary)`.

Comment: Thanks. That's definitely the solution I'll use (it seems more efficient than an if statement checking if a key is in a list every iteration)

Comment: Two ways to improve this: 1) Use a set literal: `{1, 2, 3}` instead of `set([1, 2, 3])` 2) The `.keys()` method of a dictionary returns a special object called a [dictionary view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) that behaves like a set, so you can do `-` on it directly. With this, you can change it to `for key in dictionary.keys() - {1, 2, 3}:`

Comment: True @sethmmorton, thanks. I originally had `dictionary.keys()` as in the question, but felt `set(dictionary)` looked cleaner & then of course it made sense (for symmetry) to use `set` throughout. But you are right, I've updated the answer with these suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

```
for key in [k for k in dictionary.keys() if k not in [1,2,3]]:
   ... do something
```

Comment: `dictionary` instead of `dictionary.keys()` should do.

Comment: If you used a generator (`(` and `)`) instead of a list comprehension (`[` and `]`) it would have same effect but not create a temporary list, which would both use less memory and run faster.

Answer (score 2):

A technique to bypass a few iterations from a loop would be to use **`continue`**.

```py
dictionary = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3 : 3, 4: 4}

for key in dictionary:
   if key in {1, 2, 3}:
      continue
   print(key)
```

Comment: Can you explain the statement “The lookup over the dictionary keys happens in place”?

Comment: that was to highlight that it looks up the dict's keyset directly without creating additional sets. it's not applicable to my answer though, let me remove it.